# Cosa significa "non lo avrebbero avuto della compagnia brontolona" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *L'isola*, di Giani Stuparich, ho letto:

> Non, lui **non lo non lo avrebbero avuto della compagnia brontolona**; a lui sarebbe bastato, all'ultimo momento, il rettangolo dove era sepolto suo padre: là si sarebbe ricongiunto con la terra magra dell'isola natale, e il suo nome sarebbe stato inciso sotto il nome di suo padre nella pietra modesta ricavata da quella stessa terra.

Nel paragrafo precedente a questo, l'io narante che formula questo pensiero parla dei suoi compaesani (quelli che sono rimasti a vivere sull'isola natale, mentre lui invece ne era partito da giovane e aveva avuto una vita di marinaio) in confronto con sé stesso in questi termini:

> Chi aveva traversato cinquanta volte l'Atlantico o navigato per il Pacifico, chi aveva corso l'avventura degli armamenti nei vari cantieri d'Europa e d'America,  non poteva pacificarsi, dentro un orticello dalle erbe aromatiche, a guardar scorrere le nubi sopra il suo capo, o cullandosi in una barchetta mirare lo specchio del porto. Correva rischio di diventare come Fabrizio: con quella sua lunga faccia gialla piena di borse e con gli occhi mollicci, sembrava un vecchio mastino rabbioso, inchiodato alla catena, che non si fosse mai mosso più in là di die metri dal suo canile; o come Antonio, che, senza denti, col mento sempre apoggiato al pomo del bastone, le palpebre rosse e corrose, pareva un ricoverato dell'ospizio di mendicità.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/brontolone)
 ho trovato che l'aggettivo "brontolone" significa "che ha il vizio di brontolare continuamente, o si mostra sempre scontento". Tuttavia, non riesco a capire del tutto bene il senso della frase "non lo avrebbero avuto della compagnia brontolona" che appare nel testo. "La compagnia brontolona" è il gruppo di questi compaesani? La frase vuol dire che lui non vuol far parte di questo gruppo? Non dovrebbe essere "non lo avrebbero avuto ***nella*** compagnia brontolona"? Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Comment: Secondo me la tua interpretazione del senso della frase è corretta; il personaggio non vuol tornare per far parte della "compagnia brontolona" dei compaesani (che sembra disprezzare) e si "accontenta" di tornare all'isola natale da morto. 
Il _della_ al posto di _nella_ potrebbe 
1) essere un refuso
2) essere una costruzione volutamente un po' sgrammaticata ma accettabile nel parlato che assomiglia ad espressioni tipo "_avere (qualcuno) dei nostri_" o "_avere (qualcuno) dalla nostra parte_"

Comment: Suona anche a me come a Riccardo, e aggiungo alle locuzioni forse imparentate “essere della partita” e simili.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Concordo pienamente con la tua interpretazione, e penso che dovresti convertire il tuo commento in una risposta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secondo me la tua interpretazione del senso della frase è corretta; il personaggio non vuol tornare per far parte della "compagnia brontolona" dei compaesani (che sembra disprezzare in quanto rappresentano l'antitesi della sua vita avventurosa) e si *"accontenta"* di tornare all'isola natale per rimanere solamente una volta defunto.

Il *della* al posto di *nella* potrebbe

1. essere un refuso
2. essere una costruzione volutamente un po' sgrammaticata ma accettabile nel parlato che assomiglia ad espressioni tipo *"avere (qualcuno) dei nostri"* o *"avere (qualcuno) dalla nostra parte"*.

Il commento di @DaG aggiunge anche le espressioni (simili) come *“essere della partita”*.

Comment: Ho aggiunto "per rimanere" perché, infatti, il personaggio è in quel momento sull'isola, ma è andato con l'intenzione di fare una breve visita (consapevole che è probabilmente l'ultima perché è malato di cancro e sta per morire).